# Google Sheets - Is there a way to automatically import data from one sheet to a calendar?

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, google-sheets-formula

The current project I am working on has three separate Google sheets that each include company events and their respective deadlines.

I have constructed a basic working calendar on Google Sheets and would like to automatically populate the calendar with the events as they are added to the other three Google Sheets. I am wondering if there is a way for updated to the deadline sheets to automatically get updated on the calendar sheet.

For instance, if one of the sheets was updated with "Newsletter Deadline" as the event name and 07.04.2021 as the deadline, is there a way for the name of the event to automatically be added to the calendar on the correct date?

I have successfully used IMPORTRANGE to get the events on the calendar, but this is still a manual process and, without it being automatic, is barely any better than manually copying and pasting the events on the calendar.

Thank you very much!

[Example of how the calendar will look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REI0D.png)

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9egE9.png)

Comment: Just to clarify, on the sample you've shared, if one of the 3 sheets was updated with  "Newsletter Deadline" as the event name and 07.04.2021 as the deadline, do you mean you want to add these updated event detail to a Calendar ID as a new event? Also, you've mentioned about "calendar sheet" & it is quite confusing if you're referring to a Google sheet with calendar data Or an actual Google Calendar ID where you want to add the updated events into. Would you mind sharing additional sample screenshots or images to better visualize the process you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello Irvin and thank you for your reply.
I have added two images; one of what the final calendar will look like and another of some sample data I am working with.

I have collected the dates I would like to add onto one google sheet tab on the same document as the calendar I am creating. Hopefully this will help when I try to add the data to the calendar I am constructing.

Please note that I am not trying to link this to the Calendar feature of Google Drive. I am only trying to collect all events on their respective dates on the calendar in Sheets.

Thank you again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional details. If you want to automate the adding of the event name to a calendar sheet on the correct date based on the deadline, you'd need to use Apps Script.

You can try [creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) in your spreadsheet file. Just copy and paste the sample script that you can play with below and save it:

> **NOTE**: This script runs via [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger and it is designed to work on a month calendar sheet basis (e.g. there should be a sheet calendar named after a full month like "June" with dates inside it & with 6 empty slots per date, this is based on the sample calendar sheet you've shared).

```
function onEdit() {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //The data sheet that contains event name & deadline
    var selectedRow = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow();
    var eventName = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(selectedRow,ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getColumn()-1).getValue(); //The Event name is on col A or column 1
    var deadline = Utilities.formatDate(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(selectedRow,2).getValue(), "GMT+8", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //The Deadline is on col B or column 2
    var month = Utilities.formatDate(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(selectedRow,2).getValue(), "GMT+8", "MMMM"); //Gets the full month name of the inputted deadline from sheet data
    var calendar = ss.getSheetByName(month); //The gets the month calendar sheet based on the deadline month inputted
    var calRows = calendar.getDataRange().getLastRow();
    var calCol = calendar.getDataRange().getNumColumns();
    
    Logger.log("Event Name:\n"+eventName+"\nDealine:\n"+deadline);


    for(row = 3; row <= calRows; row++){
      for(col = 1; col <= calCol; col++ ){
        if(calendar.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){
          //Skip empty cells
        }else{
          var calDate = Utilities.formatDate(calendar.getRange(row,col).getValue(), "GMT+8", "dd/MM/yyyy");
          if(calDate == deadline){ //Find date on calendar column
            addEvent(calendar, eventName, row, col);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }catch(e){
    //Ignore Exceptions
  }
}

function addEvent(calendar, eventName, row, col){
  var totalRow = row+6; //Every date on the calendar has 6 empty cell slots where the event will be added
  for(row = row; row <= totalRow; row++){
    if(calendar.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){
      calendar.getRange(row,col).setValue(eventName);
      Logger.log("Added \""+eventName+"\" to "+calendar.getRange(row,col).getA1Notation());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Result:**

> Here's a sample data sheet where the Event name & the deadline date are inputted

[image]

> Here's a sample calendar sheet named "June" with 6 empty cell slots per date

[image]

> After inputting the deadline `04 Jun` on the sample data sheet and then pressing enter, the event name `Newsletter Deadline` will be automatically added to the "June" calendar on the exact date of the deadline, as seen below:

[image]

> Here's a sample execution log results

[image]